# Select most recent distinct

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I am working on a report in SQL Server but cant seem to get it right.  How can I return the a unique JNJobID's most recent JNNote joined to my Jobs table?

```
Select
    JobNotesID  
   ,JNJobID 
   ,JNDate      
   ,JNNote
From [JobNotes] Left JOIN Jobs ON [JobNotes].JNJobID = Jobs.JobID
```

Jobs Table

```
JobID   ProjectNum     
 6972   PN1
 6973   PN2
 6974   PN3
```

JobNotes Table

```
JobNotesID  JNJobID JNDate                       JNNote    
 11800      6972    2016-03-15 00:00:00.000     Example 1
 11874      6972    2016-03-17 00:00:00.000     Example 2
 12181      6972    2016-03-25 00:00:00.000     Example 3
 12006      6973    2016-03-21 00:00:00.000     Example 4
 11961      6974    2016-03-18 00:00:00.000     Example 5
 11924      6974    2016-03-17 00:00:00.000     Example 6
```

**Would return**

```
   JobID    ProjectNum          JNNote  
 6972        PN1               Example 3
 6973        PN2               Example 4
 6974        PN3               Example 6
```

Comment: This is a very frequent question and there are plenty of suitable duplicates tagged as [tag:greatest-n-per-group], but the one I choose as duplicate target has the solution and should suit you.

Comment: Thank you.  I am still looking for a solution on how to join the greatest-n-per-group results to another query based upon the JNJobID to link it to Jobs Table with JobID.

Comment: Look at this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/af00e/1

Comment: That returned exactly what I wanted when all of the left joins were added.  I should have mentioned earlier that the query is going into an MS Access report.  Unfoturnately I dont believe partition by row_number is supported.  I will reorganize my question and ask at a later date.

Comment: SELECT  customerID, CustomerName, AStreetAddress,  ProjectNum, JobOwner, JobSubStatusID,  Status, JNJobID, JNNote
FROM (
    SELECT
   customerID, CustomerName, AStreetAddress,  ProjectNum, JobOwner, JobSubStatusID,  Status, JNJobID, JNNote
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JNJobID ORDER BY JNDate DESC) AS r
    FROM JobNotes

Comment: Left JOIN Jobs ON JobNotes.JNJobID = Jobs.JobID
 Left JOIN Addresses ON Jobs.JobAddressID = Addresses.AddressID
 Left JOIN Customers ON Jobs.JobCustomerID = Customers.CustomerID 
 Left JOIN Status ON Jobs.JobSubStatusID = Status.StatusID
) x 
WHERE r = 1 and customerID = 134 and jobsubstatusid <> 14 and jobsubstatusid <> 15 and jobsubstatusid <> 16 and jobsubstatusid <> 42 and jobsubstatusid <>38 and jobsubstatusid <>75

Comment: No, row_number is not supported in Access. You would have to use the query with the max function instead,

Answer (score -1):

You could use a the analytic version of `max()` to help recognize which row is the most recent for each ID.  That requires a CTE or inline view:

```
select
  n.JNNote
from (
    select *, max(JNDate) over (partition by JNJobID) as maxDate
    from JobNotes
  ) n
where n.JNDate = n.maxDate
```

That does suppose that there are never two notes for the same job on the same date.